# How can I generate module graphs for my multi-module Android project?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a [multi-module Android project](https://www.github.com/android/nowinandroid) and I'd like to generate module dependency graphs for each of the modules. I can use the [Module Graph Assert plugin](https://github.com/jraska/modules-graph-assert) to manually generate each graph using the command:

```
./gradlew generateModulesGraphvizText -Pmodules.graph.output.gv=my_module_dependency_graph.gv -Pmodules.graph.of.module=:my_module
```

But this requires me to manually write each module name into the command.

I can obtain the list of module names using `./gradlew projects`, then do some text formatting in bash to execute the above command for each module, however, I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of achieving this? Ideally by having a single gradle task which can then be called in CI.